# .Net Web.Config Transformations, replace entire ConnectionString section

Tags: .net, web-config-transform

I've been using web.config transforms with good success. I've just recently implemented connection strings encryption and am unsure how to modify my Release transform.

Before hand I was simply replacing the setting by using the locator for name.

Now that the settings are encrypted, there is no name.

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="Pkcs12Provider">
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes192-cbc" />
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <KeyName>rsaKey</KeyName>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>CipherValueHere</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedKey>
  </KeyInfo>
  <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>CipherValueHere</CipherValue>
  </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

How can I update my transform to replace the entire connection strings section with this? Is there a locator for the element name "connectionStrings"?

Many thanks,
John

Answer (score 7):

To replace entire connectionString section use the below code

```
<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
```

`xdt:Transform="Replace"` Will do the trick. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, if you leave out the Locator it automatically applies it to the element.